# How to make a setTimeout to call a setInterval to make it execute after some time?

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval, delay, clearinterval

I want my `doSomething` to be executed after some amount of time different than the `interval` of the `setInterval`, so I used `setTimeout(doSomething, 5000);` so I could call `doSomething` after say 5 seconds, but that doesn't seem to happen.

Regarding that I need to use `clearInterval` for the `setInterval` to stop executing in the condition I declared, and I need to have an `interval` time for the `setInterval` to be different from the delay of `doSomething` execution start, how can I make `doSomething` to start executing after 5 seconds?

```js
function doSomething() {
  let a = 1;
  return setInterval(() => {
    console.log(a);
    if (a < 6) {
      a++;
    } else {
      return a = 1;
      clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

var id = doSomething();
setTimeout(doSomething, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var id = doSomething();` calls the function (and thus starts the interval) immediately.
Since both the `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()` are within the same function, there is no need to return the interval ID. Just keep track of it locally in the function. That way you only need to invoke `doSomething()` and it will start and stop by itself.

Lastly, note that `setInterval()`'s first invocation will not be immediately, but also wait for the given delay. So if you want the first invocation to be after 5 seconds, you will need to subtract the `1000` of the `setInterval()` from the `5000` of the `setTimeout()`. (Or alternatively invoke the repeated function manually immediately.)

```js
function doSomething() {
  let a = 1;
  let intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(a);
    if (a < 6) {
      a++;
    } else {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

setTimeout(doSomething, 4000);
```

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem and specially sharing you knowledge with me!

Comment: I have a little question here, how can I set `a = 1` inside else condition?

Comment: @christy Just like that, but it wont have any effect. The `a` variable is scoped within the `doSomething()` function. When the function has completed and the interval is cleared, it doesn't really exist any more. There is no way to access it and will eventually be collected by the [garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)).

Comment: Learned something new, Bless you! :)

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout run `doSomething` about 4s delay
and `doSomething` do the first console.log about 1s delay
so the first first console.log start after 4s + 1s == 5s delay

```js
function doSomething() {
  let a = 1
    , id = setInterval(() => {
          console.log(a++);
          if (a > 5)  clearInterval(id);
        }, 1000);
  }
setTimeout( doSomething, 4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all. If you call the function that creates an interval, it will create an interval. You cannot call the function and expect it to have a timeout if you dont use a timeout.

This works:

```
function foo() {
    var i = 0;
    var iId = setInterval(() => {
        console.log('Hello World -' + i);
        i++;
        if (i > 5) {
            clearInterval(iId);
        }
    }, 1000);   
}
```

then:

```
setTimeout(() => { foo(); }, 5000)
```

Answer (score -1):

try doing it like this

```
function doSomething() {
        let a = 1;
        return setInterval(() => {
            console.log(a);
            if (a < 6) {
                a++;
            } else {
                clearInterval(id)
                return a = 1;
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    var id = doSomething();
    setTimeout(doSomething, 5000);
```

Comment: There is no difference in the result!